# Qual a melhor forma de adicionar campos ENUM no model do Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Preciso referênciar os números do campo `status` do banco de dados, que estão com o formato `ENUM`, com os nomes do meu `model`.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

#### models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   # definir constantes
   PUBLICADO = 1
   SUSPENSO  = 2
   SOMETHING = 3

   # ???
end
```

#### controllers/lista.rb

```
class ListaController < ApplicationController
   # preciso buscar algo assim:
   Item.status
   Item.status.publicado
   Item.status.suspenso
   Item.status.something
end
```

Comment: tem alguma coisa aqui : http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/708-clever-enums-in-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum status: { publicado: 1, suspenso: 2, something: 3 }
end
```

### Buscas

```
# item.update! status: 1
item.publicado!
item.publicado? # => true
item.status # => "publicado"

# item.update! status: 2
item.suspenso!
item.suspenso? # => true
item.status    # => "suspenso"

# item.update! status: 1
item.status = "publicado"

# item.update! status: nil
item.status = nil
item.status.nil? # => true
item.status      # => nil
```

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo, eu estava tentando assim, porém descobri que essa opção só está disponivel no Rails 4.1+.

Comment: Você quer a resposta pra alguma versão específica de Rails?

Comment: Não, deu certo! Meu Rails, era o 4.0. Atualizei para o 4.1.